# Differences between Buffered streams in Java and working with socket in C++?

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I'm trying to work with sockets in C++.  The only work with sockets I have ever done was in Java (I created an IRC bot, to be specific) and the code I used looked like the following -

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                             new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReater(
                             new InputStreamWriter(socket.getInputStream()));
```

then for my bot to read I would get a new thread and initiate a while loop -

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) ...
```

And to write -

```
writer.write(text);
writer.flush();
```

Now I'm attempting to do so in C++ and things are of course at a lower level and I don't quite understand what I'm doing.  I looked for some tutorials on using `winsock.h` and tried them all to no avail.  A friend of mine recommended the socket library `sdl_net`.

My question is how would my code in C++ look different compared to the code I used for my IRC bot in Java?  Also, what is the difference between the "Buffered" streams in Java and my lower-level socket work in C++?

Comment: I'd suggest using [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio) library for high-level C++ network code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your main question, this tutorial shows you roughly what the C++ would look like:

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c

Fundamentally, you need to use the `socket()` and `connect()` calls to instead of `new Socket()`.

The C++ streams are similar to the raw `socket.get(Output|Input)Stream()` streams in that there is no buffering being performed.  The `Buffered(Output|Input)Stream` stores the written/read bytes in a buffer instead of writing through to the underlying stream for every call to `write()`/`read()`.  Calling `flush()` forces the buffered data to be written through.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of any buffering is to provide function to extract/store data in chunks( for example reading a complete line ) and increase performance.

Buffering is different from socket or any other similar API. The underlying input device(socket for example) does not need to be aware of upper level of buffering. At the same time buffering does not make a distinction whether the underlying input is from keyboard or socket or from any other device.
In case of Java to use BufferedReader class, for example, the underlying input class must provide some interfaces which can be used to read/write data in chunks of characters or words, for example.

So what BufferedWriter does here is to store your data whether written in character by character or word by word and only flush it(send to the input device, here socket)  when flush is called explicitly or it is passed '\n' or it's object gets destroyed or it's buffer is full( say maxlen is 1024 chars).

Similaraly in case of BufferedReader, if you read single character from socket, it internally tries to read some 1024 characters and returns you single character. For next reads till 1024 characters it saves previous time consuming socket calls and serves you quickly from it's internal read buffer till it gets emply.

You can implement the same Buffered classes in c++ easily which wrap the socket system call providing exactly same facilities to you. For buffering you can use strstream/stringstream std classes for reading/writing the strings and you'll understand the use of using them.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation.  Thanks